# how to split .csv data in python?

Tags: python, csv

When I split my csv file using this method:

```
with open(fname) as f:    
for line in f:
    a = line.strip().split()
```

I get an expected output which is:

```
['Chicago', 'White', 'Sox,"Valentin,', 'Jose","5,000,000",Outfielder,,,,']
['Detroit', 'Tigers,"Bernero,', 'Adam","314,000",Pitcher,,,,']
```

and so on...

how to split this data into right pieces (team, player, salary, position)?

Data set (in xls) is here:

```
American League Baseball Salaries (2003)            

Team                 Player          Salary     Position

New York Yankees    Acevedo, Juan   9,00,000    Pitcher
New York Yankees    Anderson, Jason 3,00,000    Pitcher
New York Yankees    Clemens, Roger  1,01,00,000 Pitcher
New York Yankees    Contreras, Jose 55,00,000   Pitcher
```

Comment: please attach the contents of csv file you are reading from ?

Comment: For csv data it is better to use csv module

Comment: @bshuster13 this way I split their names and salaries

Comment: What separates the columns, a tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `zip` function to get the columns of your file and also use `csv` module for reading a `csv` file :

```
import csv

with open('file_.csv','rb') as f :
    csvreader=csv.reader(f,delimiter=' ')
    print zip(*csvreader)
```

And for huge files use `itertools.izip` :

```
import csv
from itertools import izip
with open('file_.csv','rb') as f :
    csvreader=csv.reader(f,delimiter=' ')
    print list(izip(*csvreader))
```

As `izip` returns a generator if you want to loop over it you don't need `list` (its for printing the content)

Also note that you need to use a correct delimiter i used `space` for instance,you can change it an use the correct delimiter!

also you can put your result in a dictionary :

```
import csv
from itertools import izip
with open('file_.csv','rb') as f :
    csvreader=csv.reader(f,delimiter='\t')
    keys=next(csvreader)
    a=izip(*csvreader)
    d=dict(zip(keys,a))

print d
print d['Salary']
```

result :

```
{'Salary': ('9,00,000', '3,00,000', '1,01,00,000', '55,00,000'), 'Player': ('Acevedo, Juan', 'Anderson, Jason', 'Clemens, Roger', 'Contreras, Jose'), 'Position': ('Pitcher', 'Pitcher', 'Pitcher', 'Pitcher'), 'Team': ('New York Yankees', 'New York Yankees', 'New York Yankees', 'New York Yankees')}
('9,00,000', '3,00,000', '1,01,00,000', '55,00,000')
```

Comment: It's a good method but now it's unclear, for example, how to print only salaries

Answer (score 0):

split uses whitespace as the default delimeter. If you want to use a different string, pass it as an argment to split. In this case, to split by comas:

```py
with open(fname) as f:    
for line in f:
    a = line.strip().split(',')
```

Answer (score 0):

format your csv as follows

```
Team,Player,Salary,Position
"New York Yankees","Acevedo, Juan","9,00,000","Pitcher"
"New York Yankees","Anderson, Jason","3,00,000","Pitcher"
"New York Yankees","Clemens, Roger","1,01,00,000","Pitcher"
"New York Yankees","Contreras, Jose","55,00,000","Pitcher"
```

Then use following python code to get values in list of dictionaries suitable for further processing

```
import csv
f=open('file.csv')
datareader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
headers = datareader.next()

datalist=[]    
for row in datareader:
    data={}
    for i in range(4):
        data[headers[i]] = row[i]
    datalist.append(data)

for data in datalist:
    print(data)
```